# Unlocking multiple LUKS-encrypted volumes with a single password at boot (Gentoo, encrypted ZFS root, genkernel initramfs)

Tags: encryption, gentoo, zfs, luks, initramfs

With this post I am sharing a solution with the community.

I have a Gentoo system installed on a ZFS pool consisting of multiple encrypted devices. It is normally decrypted at boot as described in [this post](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8139710.html#8139710). In the file `/etc/default/grub` I add to the kernel line:

```
RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="dozfs crypt_roots=UUID=aaaaaaaa crypt_roots=UUID=bbbbbbbb ..."
```

where `aaaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbbb` stand for the UUID-s of the encrypted volumes as listed in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, but there is an inconvenience: *A password must be entered once for each volume.* I use full disk encryption and 8 encrypted volumes, which would require **9** password entries on each boot, even though I use the same password for all the volumes. Quite a hassle!

Is it possible to decrypt all volumes with a single password entry?

My initramfs is created via `sys-kernel/genkernel-next-69`.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a patch for genkernel that allows for decrypting multiple volumes with a single password (save the file as `/tmp/genkernel_multicrypt.patch`):

```
diff --git a/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt-multicrypt.sh b/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt-multicrypt.sh
new file mode 100755
index 0000000..848f06a
--- /dev/null
+++ b/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt-multicrypt.sh
@@ -0,0 +1,88 @@
+#!/bin/sh
+
+MULTICRYPT_MAX_TRIES=4
+
+multicrypt_all_volumes_mapped()
+{
+    local k=0
+
+    while true; do
+        eval local voltype='"${MULTICRYPT_type'${k}'}"'
+        k=$(( k+1 ))
+
+        [ -n "$voltype" ] || return 0
+
+        local m=0
+        while true; do
+            eval local vol='"${MULTICRYPT_'${voltype}${m}'}"'
+            [ -n "$vol" ] || break
+            [ -e "/dev/mapper/${voltype}${m}" ] || return 1
+            m=$(( m+1 ))
+        done
+    done
+
+    return 0
+}
+
+multicrypt_open_volumes()
+{
+    local pass="$1"; shift
+
+    local k=0
+
+    while true; do
+        eval local voltype='"${MULTICRYPT_type'${k}'}"'
+        k=$(( k+1 ))
+
+        [ -n "$voltype" ] || return 0
+
+        local m=0
+        while true; do
+            local volname="${voltype}${m}"
+
+            eval local vol='"${MULTICRYPT_'${volname}'}"'
+            [ -n "$vol" ] || break
+
+            echo Decrypting vol ${volname} ${vol} ...
+            echo -n "$pass" | ${CRYPTSETUP_BIN} luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/${vol} "${volname}" -d - || return 1
+            
+            m=$(( m+1 ))
+        done
+    done
+}
+
+multicrypt_execute() {
+
+    [ -z "${MULTICRYPT_type0}" ] && return 1   # multicrypt not requested
+
+    local root_or_swap=
+    if [ -n "${CRYPT_ROOTS}" ] || [ -n "${CRYPT_SWAPS}" ]; then
+        root_or_swap=1
+    fi
+
+    if ! multicrypt_all_volumes_mapped; then
+        echo "Opening multiple encrypted partitions..."
+    fi
+
+    local try=0
+    while ! multicrypt_all_volumes_mapped && [ "$try" -lt "$MULTICRYPT_MAX_TRIES" ]; do
+        try=$(( try+1 ))
+
+        echo -n "Password (try $try of $MULTICRYPT_MAX_TRIES): "
+        read -s pass
+        echo ""
+
+        multicrypt_open_volumes "$pass"
+
+        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
+            echo "ERROR: Decrypting one or more volumes failed."
+        fi
+    done
+
+    if [ -n "${root_or_swap}" ]; then
+        # We postponed the initialization of raid devices
+        # in order to avoid to assemble possibly degraded
+        # arrays.
+        start_volumes
+    fi
+}
diff --git a/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt.sh b/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt.sh
index 0e7c863..0515446 100755
--- a/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt.sh
+++ b/defaults/initrd.d/00-crypt.sh
@@ -4,6 +4,7 @@
 . /etc/initrd.d/00-devmgr.sh
 . /etc/initrd.d/00-splash.sh
 . /etc/initrd.d/00-fsdev.sh
+. /etc/initrd.d/00-crypt-multicrypt.sh
 
 CRYPTSETUP_BIN="/sbin/cryptsetup"
 KEY_MNT="/mnt/key"
@@ -285,6 +286,8 @@ _open_luks() {
 
 start_luks() {
 
+    multicrypt_execute && return 0
+
     local root_or_swap=
     if [ -n "${CRYPT_ROOTS}" ] || [ -n "${CRYPT_SWAPS}" ]; then
         root_or_swap=1
```

The patch must be applied to genkernel as root in directory `/usr/share/genkernel`:

```
su

# Make a backup of genkernel if something goes wrong.
cp -r /usr/share/genkernel /root/genkernel-backup

cd /usr/share/genkernel
patch -p1 < /tmp/genkernel_multicrypt.patch
```

If everything goes right, the patch will be applied and you will not see any error messages.

**Usage**

**First make sure your disks can be decrypted using the same password!!!**

The patch modifies genkernel's initial ramdisks to support the following additional input parameters:

```
MULTICRYPT_type0=boot
MULTICRYPT_type1=root
MULTICRYPT_type2=tank

MULTICRYPT_boot0=aaaaaaaaa

MULTICRYPT_root0=bbbbbbbbb
MULTICRYPT_root1=ccccccccc

MULTICRYPT_tank0=ddddddddd
MULTICRYPT_tank1=eeeeeeeee
...
```

In the above example you can freely choose how many types you want to have, I used 3: `boot`, `root`, `tank`. For each type you can have one or more volume UUIDs as shown above.

**Make sure the UUIDs are present in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.**
**Make sure the UUIDs are exact! Typos can lead to an unbootable system!**

The devices will be added to the device mapper as `boot0`, `root0`, `root1`, etc.

Now, the kernel line must be modified as follows (simply append all parameters mentioned above to the kernel line along with your regular ones, for example `dolvm`, `dozfs`, etc.).

**Do not delete your original kernel line yet, simply comment it out in case you want to revert.**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="MULTICRYPT_type0=boot MULTICRYPT_type1=root MULTICRYPT_type2=tank MULTICRYPT_boot0=aaaaaaaaa MULTICRYPT_root0=bbbbbbbbb MULTICRYPT_root1=ccccccccc MULTICRYPT_tank0=ddddddddd MULTICRYPT_tank1=eeeeeeeee ..."

# As per standard grub configuration, we need to load the necessary modules and enable encryption:
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt search_fs_uuid cryptodisk luks linux"  # zfs lvm etc. if necessary
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="y"
```

When this chore is done, we can call genkernel do generate the new initramfs. Make sure you make a backup copy of your old one to enable easy recovery if something goes wrong. Compiling kernel and modules is not necessary.

Also, write down your **original** kernel line on a piece of paper, so that you can type it in Grub in case the system can't boot properly.

```
su
cp /boot/<YOUR-INITRAMFS> /boot/<YOUR-INITRAMFS>--copy

# This uses 8 threads for compilation, adjust accordingly.
# Add "--zfs" if your root is on ZFS.
genkernel --makeopts=-j8 --udev --luks --busybox --bootloader=grub2 --menuconfig --oldconfig --install initramfs
```

Your shiny new initramfs is installed in `/boot`. Now for the final touch - GRUB's configuration file must be generated to activate the new parameters:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

*At the time of writing grub-mkconfig generates an incorrect file that needs to be patched manually **if your root is on ZFS**. In the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` my root dataset is incorrectly specified as `/ROOT/gentoo` instead of `zroot/ROOT/gentoo` so I need to insert `zroot` in multiple locations. This should not be necessary once that particular bug is fixed.*

Done! After rebooting the following prompt will be shown:

```
Opening multiple encrypted partitions...
Password (try 1 of 4):
```

Enter your password and (fingers crossed) all volumes should decrypt.

**Troubleshooting**

If your system becomes unbootable, you can use your old initramfs that we saved. When the Grub menu is shown, hit `E` and retype your original kernel line, appending "--saved" to your initramfs filename. This should boot your system as it was before.

If you are not satisfied with the patch, restore your original genkernel from `/root/genkernel-backup` to `/usr/share/genkernel`, then restore your original kernel line in `/etc/default/grub` and call genkernel and grub-mkconfig again:

```
genkernel --makeopts=-j8 --udev --luks --busybox --bootloader=grub2 --menuconfig --oldconfig --install initramfs
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

**Caveat**

For I use a full disk encryption, I still need to enter my password twice at boot. First, to decrypt `/boot` and load the kernel, then a second time to decrypt all other volumes. I am not aware of any solution for this.

State 17.02.2022